# Native crash at /system/lib/libssl.so using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

Well, this is all i have to go on, i keep getting numerous crash reports with the same error, i do NO work with the NDK for Android, flummoxed.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'motorola/falcon_verizon/falcon_cdma:4.4.2/KXB20.9-1.10-1.20/22:user/release-keys'
Revision: 'p3c0'
pid: 21814, tid: 21835, name: GAThread >>> com.broakenmedia<<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
r0 00000000 r1 00000000 r2 6489f065 r3 00000019
r4 00000008 r5 6489f066 r6 00000000 r7 ffffffff
r8 00000001 r9 40bcb130 sl 00000019 fp 6489f065
ip 5f5f9b34 sp 5f7e8918 lr 5f5ee105 pc 40bb60f6 cpsr 600f0030
d0 0000000000000000 d1 0000000000000000
d2 0000000000000000 d3 0000000000000000
d4 efc22a9ee9cf8940 d5 271b266bf2924c08
d6 1f19976e9804b757 d7 11c02467fe77c152
d8 0000000000000000 d9 0000000000000000
d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 0000000000000000 d17 0000000000000000
d18 d836b17c3b7fe0ac d19 6b3faee5dca6374b
d20 6166e68800000000 d21 000000016154be98
d22 0000000000000000 d23 0000000000000000
d24 0003000000030000 d25 0003000000030000
d26 0000002e0000002d d27 000000300000002f
d28 0100010001000100 d29 0100010001000100
d30 0000000000000000 d31 0000000000000000
scr 60000010

backtrace:
#00 pc 000270f6 /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_select_next_proto+49)
#01 pc 00007101 /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
#02 pc 0002f4ff /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl_parse_serverhello_tlsext+434)
#03 pc 000182a5 /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_get_server_hello+1004)
#04 pc 000176af /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl3_connect+566)
#05 pc 000266b1 /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_connect+20)
#06 pc 0001217b /system/lib/libssl.so (ssl23_connect+2402)
#07 pc 00027ebb /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_do_handshake+50)
#08 pc 0000af1b /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
#09 pc 0002034c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#10 pc 00050e6b /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
#11 pc 000297e0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#12 pc 00030ae8 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#13 pc 0002e180 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#14 pc 0006346d /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
#15 pc 00063491 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
#16 pc 0005815f /system/lib/libdvm.so
#17 pc 0000d240 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#18 pc 0000d3d8 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

code around pc:
40bb60d4 d02c2b00 9f0f9701 21009102 4001f81b 
40bb60e4 0801f101 eb0bb1cf eb0b0001 90030508 
40bb60f4 f8162000 f1009000 454c0a01 eb06d109 
40bb6104 4628010a f7e54622 4601eef4 29002001 
40bb6114 eb0ad00a 42b80009 eb08d3eb 9a040104 
40bb6124 42912002 e000d3da 99029e03 1c729f01 
40bb6134 7832603a b005700a 8ff0e8bd 3178f8d0 
40bb6144 2100600b bf182b00 117cf890 47706011 
40bb6154 11a4f8c0 21a8f8c0 bf004770 11acf8c0 
40bb6164 21b0f8c0 bf004770 4605b570 f8d54614 
40bb6174 460e01bc bf182800 ed70f7e5 f240480a 
40bb6184 490a6296 44014478 f7e54620 2101ed5c 
40bb6194 01bcf8c5 4631b130 f7e54622 2100ed9c 
40bb61a4 41c0f8c5 bd704608 000138b8 ffffb947 
40bb61b4 4605b570 f8d54614 460e019c bf182800 
40bb61c4 ed4cf7e5 f240480a 490a62aa 44014478 

code around lr:
5f5ee0e4 46052121 f7fe4640 6a6aef92 b13c6aab 
5f5ee0f4 000ce88d 46314638 9b084622 ef6ef7fe 
5f5ee104 e8bd2000 b53881fc b1884604 b1556a05 
5f5ee114 ffccf7ff 68036829 47906d9a f7fe4628 
5f5ee124 2000ef7c 21006220 60e12001 bd386161 
5f5ee134 b508bd38 6d5a6803 bd084790 6803b508 
5f5ee144 47906dda b508bd08 6fda6803 bd084790 
5f5ee154 6804b510 4084f8d4 bd1047a0 b513b40c 
5f5ee164 6804ab04 2b04f853 40c8f8d4 47a09301 
5f5ee174 401ce8bd 4770b002 b513b40c 6804ab04 
5f5ee184 2b04f853 40f8f8d4 47a09301 401ce8bd 
5f5ee194 4770b002 b513b40c 6804ab04 2b04f853 
5f5ee1a4 41ccf8d4 47a09301 401ce8bd 4770b002 
5f5ee1b4 6803b508 229cf8d3 bd084790 6803b508 
5f5ee1c4 22acf8d3 bd084790 6804b510 42b0f8d4 
5f5ee1d4 bd1047a0 6803b508 32b4f8d3 bd084798
```

Comment: Its a segfault with a fault address of 0.  Almost certainly a NULL pointer being dereferences.  Since its in libssl, its probably via an HTTP request.  I'd check all inputs to HTTP requests, both direct and those made by library.

Comment: Can you show how do you set up the connection specially the SSL factory snippet?

Comment: I'm not aware of any connections being made, i DO use Squares' 'RetroFit' though, should i perhaps question them?

Comment: I just googled the first line of the stacktrace. And here is it, here is the possible workaround to nearly the same issue (maybe) here http://goo.gl/hMi9oc You might need to do some configuration of the default OkClient especially how will your httpclient will handle the ssl connections, respectively its OkHttp, rather than just using the default OkHttp that OkClient instantiates.

Comment: My server does not use SSL? Nor OKHttp, unless it's combined with Retrofits backend

Comment: I am getting the similar error
    
pid: 30127, tid: 30197, name: Retrofit-Idle >>> cz.cisla <<<
    signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------

Comment: Was any fix ever found for this issue? I'm encountering the same crash.

Comment: @Prateek I'm afraid not!

Comment: And any workaround for the issue that you eventually ended up doing?

Comment: This seems like a device specific driver related issue. Can us share if its happening across multiple devices?